# How to bring map in rviz (indigo-gazebo)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Speecification First:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/ Ros Indigo / Gazrbo / P3AT/

I have used following manual to setup ros-gazebo-p3at.

[http://people.oregonstate.edu/~chungje/Code/Pioneer3dx%20simulation/ros-indigo-gazebo2-pioneer.pdf]

Teleoperation is working fine.

**Problem:** we are unable to set rviz display parameter. What to do.

Should i give more information. Please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227390/how-to-bring-map-in-rviz-(indigo-gazebo)/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have understood well, you would like to load a map on Rviz. To load a map on Rviz you have two options:

1. via a launch file
2. do it manually. Open a terminal and go to the directory where you have put your map file and run:

> rosrun map_server map_server
> sample.yaml

After you run rviz, (e.g., rosrun rviz rviz),
add Map from the bottom left tab. Then, under the topic section choose /map.

---

Originally posted by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) with karma: 79 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1